# How do I call getblocktemplate from C#'s bitcoinlib?

Tags: mining-pools, block, c#

How do I call `getblocktemplate` from the bitcoinlib package for C#?

This call does not work

```
ICoinService CoinService = new BitcoinService(useTestnet: true);
var blockTemplate = CoinService.GetBlockTemplate();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var blockTemplate = CoinService.GetBlockTemplate( new { rules=new List<string> { "segwit" } });
```

This function call requires you to specify rules for the block you want to create and in newer Bitcoin Core version, you can only create blocks following the segwit softfork rules.